# Providing support via Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, product-support

There's [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4809988/roman-koellges) who is providing support for their product when it shows up on Stack Overflow questions. They are very upfront about their affiliation and seem to be generally helpful, but the format of their answers is always something like this:

> Roman from Tower here, hi. 
>   /* Something */ 
>   If you need more assistance, please contact us: http://bit.ly/towersupport

I don't think the first and last lines add anything of value. But I came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32268630/1366033) where even the middle part was just a plea to take the diagnosis offline with the user.

I don't want to discourage companies from providing support on their own products, but this can't be done here on a user-by-user The support URL could, at best, get added to the tag if they are really committed to handling every case that comes their way.

Comment: Moreover the last line encourages answers to go off of stack overflow, which violates the very purpose of putting information here for the future.

Comment: Relevant: [Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: @Deduplicator, agreed, except some kind of signature was partially necessary to comply with "you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers".  Not that there weren't other violations when 3 out of 3 answers plugged the product.

Comment: Well, that *only* applies when you are linking to your own things, and the question isn't about that thing. In which case something much shorter, like a possessive pronoun ("my" / "our") is quite enough, it doesn't invalidate the guidance I mentioned. (He *could* take a page from hth-alf's book, and rename himself like "Roman Koellges from Towers".)

Comment: We've been noticing a pattern of this coming from certain companies lately.

Comment: @Deduplicator: On that note, I wonder if there are any meta posts along the lines of how to reconcile disclosure of affiliation with the "signatures, taglines or greetings" rule. I personally think the possessive pronoun is enough, but I think that can easily be missed at times.

Comment: I removed the greeting and signature from his answers as they add no value. His answer is worth as much as from anyone else no matter if he works at Tower or not. Also I don’t think the signature is necessary to "disclose his affiliation in his answers" because he does not promote the product in any way.

Comment: Does the tagline really not add value here? -- As a developer, I think it would be helpful to know that there was a dedicated support site (at least as a fallback). -- Doesn't really seem like spam to me (or a plea to *not* put the answer up on SO) -- I mean, you can (and should!) always come back and put the answer up afterwards ('cause if you don't that doesn't help anyone).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I seem to have stepped on a couple of toes here without even realising it. I apologize for not being fully aware of the conventions of SO.

I work at Tower as a support person and as such my goal -ultimately- is helping people. We do not encourage our users to turn to SO for support, but sometimes they do. My feeling is that they deserve our attention no matter what place they choose for their questions.

It seems as if my friendly 'support personality' is somewhat at odds with the conventions of this site and I promise to tune it down when posting here. As far as my intention to 'spam' goes I can say: There was none.

I'm sorry for any irritation I caused.

Comment: Hi Roman!  Thanks for responding! Speaking on behalf no one imparticular, we'd **love** to have your expertise to help solve problems on Stack Overflow.  There are a lot of rules and conventions here (like no taglines) that are *very* different from other internet forums where such behavior is allowed and even encouraged. No harm no foul.  Sorry to have called you at specifically; i just wanted to draw attention to the issue on Meta to have a discussion about it.

Answer (score 48):

When you have a [C#] question then it is very, very nice when [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) answers it. When you have a [Scala] question then it is very nice when [Martin Odersky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210303/martin-odersky) answers it. When you have a [jQuery] question then tops when [John Resig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6524/john-resig) answers it.

And when you have a [git-tower] question then you are *way* ahead when [Roman Koellges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4809988/roman-koellges) answers it. These people are subject experts, and they've been doing it for a long time.

Being a subject expert does not automatically make you an expert at answering Stack Overflow questions in the desired format. Many rules, some of them pretty arcane and can only be learned by studying the help center carefully or having followed meta for a while.

Unless you get help from other Stack Overflow users. Like one that edits the post and remove the clutter. From what I can see, all he has to know is that introductions and tag-lines are not appropriate. No big deal, that's a very easy edit. One that anybody can do, chastising the guy in meta is not necessary and not what we normally do with new users.

He'll probably read this post, assistance provided.

Comment: Keyword being *answers*.  The linked, now deleted, question did not even attempt to answer it above taking support offline.  This is odd and I think warrants a [discussion] as I've tagged this question.  It's certainly not meant to chastise unless you feel like being called up on Meta is chastising in and of itself.  It's a much longer medium than the comments section for the community to weigh in.  I'm certain he will come read this thread, and I hope he does, and I further hope that it doesn't discourage him from answering on topic questions here in the future.

Comment: You clearly did not actually review the linked material.

Comment: That's presumptuous, I reviewed Roman's posts.  Can't see the deleted one.

Comment: and it is awesome when [Hans Passant](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) answers your question on ??

Comment: Hmm, very snarky.  It is open season on subject experts I guess.  If you don't know then you'll never find out.

Comment: I agree that having a subject matter expert answer your question is very valuable. In the case of experts providing support for their product/project on SO, I think there's probably a lot of "it depends" on how to handle it. If the company is telling people to go to SO and then asking them to go through another channel, that's problematic. However, if their users are coming here instead of going through the appropriate support channel, sending them the right direction is in a way the correct answer, depending on the situation. If it's some paid support sales pitch, that could be unwelcome.

Comment: *"and it is awesome when Hans Passant answers your question on ??"* Well that's a secret, but one should stay a while and listen when he answers on Meta.

Answer (score 24):

No, that's definitely wrong.

This is actually a common knowledge across SE, but if by some reason it desperately needs to be pointed out, then it should be **a comment**:

> If you need more assistance, please ask for it in comments. If you have another question about %productname%, ask it as a new question, and send me a link here.

All that is based on a presupposition of that the solution is **already given** in the answer. Answer which just offers the user to move discussion outside of the SE is a pure, crystallized spam (which should be flagged to death).

Comment: …unless the question is actually off-topic on SO, of course. Not all support questions should be asked here, so putting a link to the appropriate place in a close-vote comments seems fine to me.

Comment: @Bergi: that's a great idea.

Answer (score 19):

It is probably possible to successfully use SO as an "official" means to support a product. **However, this cannot be done at the expense of SO's rules and customs.**

In this case, the opening and closing that the user has been adding to the answers is pure noise and does not belong there. It is okay to *comment* about how to seek further help onsite (and perform whatever editing is needed) when users are using the site inappropriately. However, we should not preemptively add text to our answers to inform them of this.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32268630/1366033) you pointed out as being nothing more than a plea to continue the discussion off-site has now been deleted, and rightfully so. This answer was "not an answer". If Roman repeats this too many time, he's going to find himself unable to answer questions on SO.

Comment: Let's hope he never has to be blocked.