# How to handle posts from professionals offering support on their product through other channels (e.g. e-mail)?

Tags: discussion

While reviewing posts on Stack Overflow, I stumbled on this one: [Losing connections from GCE to Google Cloud SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755826/losing-connections-from-gce-to-google-cloud-sql).

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31767981/4954037) that seems to be from a Google employee, offering support via mail. I was tempted to flag this as a link-only answer (help may be provided but the solution will not be posted here). On the other hand, the answer may be what the OP is looking for.

Is there a consensus how to handle this kind of answer? Is it just plain acceptable?

Comment: That "kind of answer" is not an answer. Downvote, flag, and carry on.

Comment: flag as what? 'not an answer'?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I thought that was implied by me saying it was not an answer.

Comment: Yes flag as not an answer, it isn't one.

Comment: Google offering support, picks up jaw from floor.  This *ought* to be converted to a comment by a moderator.  Ideally the Google employee can then take a look and write a real answer.  Probably won't happen now, SO users are deleting it.

Comment: I am a professional troubleshooter (not entirely by choice, as it happens). Can I contact you through e-mail and send you my answer?

Comment: [@Jongware](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2564301/jongware): yes, please. but post your offer to help as an answer.

Comment: Google offering support? You sure it's not a hoax?  Usually "it'll be fixed in the next version of android". For phones it therefore becomes "wait 6-12 months and buy a new phone".  Google's support strategy - coming soon to a car near you...

Comment: Related: [Providing support via Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303712/1366033)

Comment: @KyleMit: right (but not a plain duplicate). As you state in the comment there, yes, we'd be *delighted* to have Google's expertise on board! I know I was extremely pleased to see "household names" such as Mark Adler put in their voice on SO. Unfortunately, Jay Zhu approached it the wrong way. Rather than flag/delete we may consider enlightening him a bit first, before - he's new to SO! - scaring him away with pitchforks...

Comment: I do understand SO is not a support channel for clients but should we not consider the fact that a lot of others may benefit from such posts(ones with a clear answer to the query about the product ) .....Is it not what SO is supposed to be about ? :P.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

While the offered answer may very well be the one the OP is looking for, Stack Overflow is not meant to mediate between resellers and clients. Thus, even though (surely) posted with the very best of intentions, the following

[image: google offering help! really!]

is

1. **not a proper answer**. It's an offer to help.
2. **not useful for the SO community at large**. If a fruitful communication ensues between OP and Google, and they are able to resolve OP's conundrum, we may never know; people pondering the same questions can find it on SO – but unanswered.

But primarily this kind of answer is *this*:

[image: not an answer!]

Comment: beautiful image! (especially the 2nd one)

Comment: +1 for answer and +200 super unicorn rainbow points for picture styling and freehand writing.  That said you also get -15 super unicorn rainbow points for not drawing a circle around the radio button.

Comment: +10 1337 points for making the `l` look like a `7` and also leaving out the `c` in "`click`".

Comment: Could you comment on whether this would be appropriate as a *comment*?

Comment: @jpmc26: this answer? **Yes**. There is nothing wrong in asking for example data files. I do that all the time - although usually I ask for a link to a public server, so I can share the fun with other users. (Sometimes I ask for the benefits of others if I know I would not be able to solve it.) Naturally, it is expected the solution gets shared; which is less obvious if a "private communication path" gets established by sending data through email.

Comment: To be clear, the post should be flagged as "not an answer", so a mod can handle it. It shouldn't be burninated through downvotes and delete-votes, that makes us look like bureaucratic jerks.